# What happened to potential energy?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, relativity, charge, mass-energy

[image]

I was learning how charge can be virtue of a body's potential energy.Meanwhile,I was hung by this question.

[gravitational and other forces except coulombic,are assumed to be not acting on the charged bodies in the following cases]

What I thought was,if we have two charged bodies in the space interacting each other with only coulombic force(force due to property of charge).And if we suppose eliminate charge property(either by removing electrons and protons or any one of them) of one of the body,then the body from which the property of charge was eliminated gets thrown away for certain distance.Thus,converting energy stored in it by the virtue of it's charge into kinetic energy(I don't know energy get's converted into other energy or not).

Now,consider a single charged body not interacting with any other body in the space.Even if you remove charge from it,the body will not get thrown away.

So,
**is there any other energy into which potential energy stored in it by the virtue of charge got converted?**
Or
**is it that charged body has charge as the virtue of it's potential energy only when it has another charge interacting with it?**

**NOTE:** I have heard so many of them speaking about mass-energy equivalence.But I have a naive idea about it.Anyway,you can notice in the above explanation,if you eliminate the charge property of a body,by removing protons and electrons or any one of them,mass is going to reduce by certain amount.I think there might be some link with mass-energy equivalence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any other energy into which potential energy stored in it by the virtue of charge got converted?

The potential energy that you spoke of cannot be defined by one point charge. This is electrostatics 101, where we talk about a test charge that needs to be introduced in order to define that there is a field present. More over, the potential energy that is in the test charge comes from the fact that it takes force to bring it from infinity to the vicinity of the charge or vice versa.

> is it that charged body has charge as the virtue of it's potential energy only when it has another charge interacting with it?

YES!

Comment: @Programmer.I have deleted the extended question,as multiple questions were not allowed under a single title.But I would like to ask you here,**"Has the body lost any energy due to elimination of charge property?"**

Answer (score 1):

The Electrostatic Potential Energy we talk about is an energy stored in Electrostatic Field. Field is a reality and it has momentum, energy etc. stored in it. How to imagine it ? Consider that some space has a field in it. Then that space has stored energy in it in the form of field present, such that if you change the configuration of the charges creating that field, you need to apply energy and that energy is stored in the new field created by the new configuration of charges.

As a test consider the case when you brought the charges back to their original configuration, and hence did no work, supplied no energy and the field remained the same too, thus no energy was supplied to the field. So this potential energy you are talking about is a property of field and not matter actually. By matter I mean a rigid object that you can hold and move etc.

Now considering your question of the potential energy of two charged bodies. If you move those electrons and protons, and get them to a new point. Two things will happen , 1) the electric field intensity where it was previously present will get changed and of course you will take them to a new place in this universe only where they will create a new field and thus energy will again resurface as field in this new region. So change in field energy in previous place=(-)change in field energy at new place.